# from mysql to mysqli updating code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to update an old script as seen below.

```
mysql sql statement that works is:
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT products.products_id AS id, 
products_description.products_name AS name,
products.products_quantity AS quantity, products.products_weight AS weight, 
products.products_price AS price
FROM products, products_description WHERE 
products.products_id=products_description.products_id;") or 
die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
```

The mysqli statements that I can't get to work is:

```
$sql = "SELECT products_id, products_description.products_name, 
products_quantity, products_weight, products_price FROM products INNER JOIN 
products_description on products.products_id = 
products_description.products_id";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){


while(null !== ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
```

The error I receive is:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean 
given in index.php on line 19
```

the mysqli statement worked but not when I add the `products_description.products_name` to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mysqli_query() returns :
>
> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, or EXPLAIN queries it will return a mysqli_result object.
>
> For other successful queries it will return TRUE. FALSE on failure

As evident from your error, you are getting `False` as `$result` which you are then passing in `mysqli_num_rows()`, which expects as `mysqli_result`.

You need to modify your `$sql` as following as there may be ambiguous column error, if same column names exists in both tables `products` and  `products_description`.

```
$sql = "SELECT p.products_id, pd.products_name, p.products_quantity, p.products_weight, p.products_price 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN products_description pd on p.products_id = pd.products_id";
```

Comment: worked like a dream satish!!   off to learn how to do this in PDO

Comment: Good to know. May be this will also be helpful : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059